# Taking values from a certain number Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database with images related to one product, and I'd like to take those images there only from the second one.

The code to my view is this. I put a line for each image

```
@foreach($allImages as $image)
                    <a href="" class="item-thumb"> <img src="{{ asset('merchants/images/products/' . $image->image) }}" alt="little picture"></a>
                    @endforeach
```

I hope I'm clear enough on what I'd like to do...

Comment: You mean you want to skip the first image?

Comment: Yes exact, you can look at it that way, too.

Comment: You can use ->skip(1) to skip first item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@foreach($allImages->skip(1) as $image)
    <a href="" class="item-thumb"> <img src="{{ asset('merchants/images/products/' . $image->image) }}" alt="little picture"></a>
@endforeach
```

This will skip the first record

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to skip  the first image in the array

```
@foreach($allImages as $image)
    @if($loop->first){
        @continue;
    }
    else{
        <a href="" class="item-thumb"> <img src="{{ asset('merchants/images/products/' . $image->image) }}" alt="little picture"></a>
    }
@endforeach
```

I hope it is helpful for you